# WebSocket server not receiving messages immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, websocket

The Node.JS server doesn't receive the message quickly..

Server code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server
var http = require("http")
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"))

var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(port)

console.log("http server listening on %d", port)

var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server})
console.log("websocket server created")

wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
  var id = setInterval(function() {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(new Date()), function() {  })
  }, 1000)

  console.log("websocket connection open")
  ws.on("message", function(msg){
    ws.send(msg);
  })
  ws.on("close", function() {
    console.log("websocket connection close")
    clearInterval(id)
  })
})
```

Code to connect:

```
var z = new WebSocket("ws://appname.herokuapp.com/");
z.onopen = function(){ console.log("opened"); };
// ... after opened message seen in console, the following
// were typed directly into the console, a few seconds apart
z.send("H");
z.send("Hello World");
z.send("Hello World asdf");
```

Until the third send was done (even if it was a minute after the others), the server did not respond with `H` or `Hello World`; all three responses were made at the same time. How do I make the server respond in a timely manner?

(Using WireShark, I checked that the sends were actually done; they were)

Edit: The amount of requests/time before response varies each time.